# Get HTTP response body as string (BubbleWrap for RubyMotion)

Tags: http, twitter, rubymotion

Using RubyMotion (for the first time!), I want to use Twitter's search API to retrieve some recent tweets for some users so have put together the class below.

The value of `tweets` is always an empty array.  I suspect that `BW::HTTP.get(url)` spawns its own thread which is causing the issue.

Really, I just want `twitter_search_results` to return `response.body.to_str` but I am not sure how to do this.

**How do I use RubyMotion (or BubbleWrap) to put an array of Tweet objects into my UIViewController?**

```
class TweetsController
  def initialize
    @twitter_accounts = %w(dhh google)
    @tweets = []
  end

  def tweets
    twitter_search_results
    puts @tweets.count
    @tweets
  end

  def create_tweets(response)
    BW::JSON.parse(response)["results"].each do |result|
      @tweets << Tweet.new(result)
    end
  end

  def twitter_search_results
    query = @twitter_accounts.map{ |account| "from:#{account}" }.join(" OR ")
    url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#{query}"
    BW::HTTP.get(url) do |response|
      create_tweets(response.body.to_str)
    end
  end
end

class TwitterViewController < UIViewController
  def viewDidLoad
    super
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor
    @table = UITableView.alloc.initWithFrame(self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview @table
    @table.dataSource = self
    @tweets_controller = TweetsController.new
  end

  def initWithNibName(name, bundle: bundle)
    super
    self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.alloc.initWithTitle(
      "Twitter",
      image: UIImage.imageNamed('twitter.png'),
      tag: 1)
    self
  end

  def tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
    @tweets_controller.tweets.length
  end

  def tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    @reuse_id = "Tweet"
    cell = UITableViewCell.alloc.initWithStyle(UITableViewCellStyleDefault, reuseIdentifier:@reuse_id)
    cell.textLabel.text = @tweets_controller.tweets[indexPath.row].text
    return cell
  end
end

class Tweet
  attr_reader :created_at, :from_user, :text
  def initialize(tweet_result)
    @created_at = tweet_result["created_at"]
    @from_user = tweet_result["from_user"]
    @text = tweet_result["text"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full controller code below.  I've also put the [project on GitHub](https://github.com/michrome/rubymotion)

```
class TweetsController
  def initialize
    @twitter_accounts = %w(dhh google)
    @tweets = []
    create_tweets
  end

  def tweets
    @tweets
  end

  def create_tweets
    json_data = twitter_search_results.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    e = Pointer.new(:object)
    dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json_data, options:0, error: e)
    dict["results"].each do |result|
      p result.class
      p result
      @tweets << Tweet.new(result)
    end
  end

  def twitter_search_results
    query = @twitter_accounts.map{ |account| "from:#{account}" }.join(" OR ")
    url_string = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#{query}"
    url_string_escaped = url_string.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    url = NSURL.URLWithString(url_string_escaped)
    request = NSURLRequest.requestWithURL(url)
    response = nil
    error = nil
    data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error: error)
    raise "BOOM!" unless (data.length > 0 && error.nil?)
    json = NSString.alloc.initWithData(data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue here is asynchronicity.  you're almost there, I think, but the `create_tweets` method is not called before `puts @tweets`.  In this case, I would recommend using a notification, because I think they are good ;-)

```
TweetsReady = 'TweetsReady'  # constants are nice
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter.postNotificationName(TweetsReady, object:@tweets)

In your controller, register for this notification in `viewWillAppear` and unregister in `viewWillDisappear`

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: 'tweets_ready:', name: TweetsReady, object:nil)  # object:nil means 'register for all events, not just ones associated with 'object'
# ...
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter.removeObserver(self, name:TweetsReady, object:nil)
```

and you tweets_ready method should implement your UI changes.

```
def tweets_ready(notification)
  @table.reloadData
end
```

Comment: Stop by #rubymotion and hit me up there if you hit a snag. :-)

Comment: I find it interesting that the solution was to not use BW::HTTP. Is its missing blocking HTTP requests a bug in your view, @colinta?

Comment: I've fixed my answer - Mike, whose answer is below, eschews BW::HTTP in favor of NSURLRequest and family.  I recommended the use of Notifications, and my original answer is above.  I disagree - strongly - with the VERY LIBERAL edit that Mike made to my answer.

Comment: To answer your question about the missing feature being a bug: I wouldn't call it a bug, but it *is* a missing feature.  but the bubblewrap developers are an active group, and would likely accept - or consider - a pull request that adds that feature!

Comment: Lastly: I strongly discourage the use of blocking requests.  I think that asynchronous requests are a *good thing*, and we should program to support them, not try to avoid them.  Okay, I'm done :-)

Comment: Sincere apologies for the editing of my answer over yours, @colinta, no idea how that happened but was obviously user error on my part!

Comment: Glad it all got sorted!  Sorry to sound so snarky in these comments (I removed the one below).  I must have been in a bad mood.  Happy coding!

Comment: I'd still second colinta's response.  Async whenever possible to avoid blocking the UI. Design for async, and you can pull those updates in the background whenever you want, not just when that particular UI is front and center.